# I am new to HTML and I want to add an image inside of a function

Tags: html, image, function

I am creating my first website and want to create a button that, when clicked, shows an image. I have looked for the answer, but can't find it. 
This is my current code, I basically just need to know where to go from here.

```
<button onclick=Taco()>Taco</button>
  <script> function Taco(){
 }
  </script>
```

Comment: put img tag with display none style. then show ot by javascript code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: There are a huge number of different ways to achieve this. Personally, I would probably have the image already on the page, and add a CSS class that make it visible, but it depends on the situation. You should probably expand your explanation, or come up with an attempt yourself.

Comment: Ok thank you so much :). Sorry, this was my first question. I am not entirely sure the etiquette I am supposed to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do it is to first make an image element, have it hidden at the beginning,  and then show it at the function call Taco().

```html
<button onclick="taco()">Taco</button>
<img src="your-pic.png" id="image" display="none">
<script>
document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
function taco(){
  document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn 'javascript' for implementing actions that you want on the page.

And there is a library called 'jQuery'. It is based on Javascript. But it makes things simpler and easier.

It has a function called 'hide()' and another one called 'show()'.

You can easily implement the feature that you want with this two functions.

And you will need a click event. You can do this like this:

```
var isClicked = 0; // as a global variable.

$('#yourButtonId').on('click', function(){
    if(isClicked == 0){
       $('#yourImageId').hide();
       isClicked = 1;
    }else{
       $('#yourImageId').show();
       isClicked = 0;
    }
});
```

EXAMPLE:

```js
var isClicked = 0;

$('#yourButtonId').on('click', function(){
  if(isClicked == 0){
     $('#yourImageId').hide();
     isClicked = 1;
  }else{
     $('#yourImageId').show();
     isClicked = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<button id="yourButtonId">I'M BUTTON</button>
<img id="yourImageId" src="http://ph.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201701/1032932_375794_0104.jpeg"/>
</body>
```

You can also use your 'taco' function as below:

```
function taco(){
    if(isClicked == 0){
       $('#yourImageId').hide();
       isClicked = 1;
    }else{
       $('#yourImageId').show();
       isClicked = 0;
    }
}
```

EXAMPLE:

```js
var isClicked = 0;

function taco(){
  if(isClicked == 0){
     $('#yourImageId').hide();
     isClicked = 1;
  }else{
     $('#yourImageId').show();
     isClicked = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button id="yourButtonId" onclick="taco()">I'M BUTTON</button>
<img id="yourImageId" src="http://ph.cctoday.co.kr/news/photo/201701/1032932_375794_0104.jpeg"/>
</body>
```

How to use jQuery?

Check here: https://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/default.asp

Comment: Added samples as well. I hope this is helpful.